# A deployed bokeh server displays a blank plot, but everything is fine locally

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to deploy to the general Internet a Bokeh app, but even though widgets and divs are rendered properly, the actual plot is not showing at all.

I have searched a bit and found this recent [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856999/bokeh-plots-just-bring-up-a-blank-window) on StackOverflow that seemed similar to my issue, but I'm not sure the same thing is happening with my app. Besides, I don't quite understand the proposed solution.

Moreover, when I run the app locally with the command `bokeh serve --show /path/myapp.py`, everything runs well.

Could someone enlighten me? I have joined an image of the Chrome's console.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I have tried to replicate the situation with AWS. I uploaded my .py app and ran `bokeh serve app.py --port=80 --host='*'` from the EC2 instance. I have the same problem, everything is there except for the plot itself. This suggests that something is wrong in the code itself.

---

[image: console]

Comment: How are you deploying to the general Internet as you wrote it? Are you using reverse-proxying? are you using Apache server? Nginx server? using SSL?

Comment: I'm using Apache only without reverse-proxying or SSL. I don't know if it can help, but the command I'm using to run my tests is "bokeh serve --show rrq_pour_server.py --host *:5006".

Comment: I needed reverse-proxying. I post what worked for me below. Maybe you just need to put the port under --port parameter: "bokeh serve --show rrq_pour_server.py --host * --port 5006"

Comment: I tried the command you suggested, but with no results. I'll check if I could make it work using your solution, and I'll post something here if I succeed.

Comment: --host * doesn't work for me either. It wants the server_name:80.  or IPnumber:80 as I show in my suggested solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned earlier in the edit, the actual problem wasn't liked to the server itself. Some code in my .py file was causing the browser to not displaying the plot.

Here is the problematic code:

```
p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
    function (tick) {
        var mapping = {1.25: "20 000 $", 5.25: "50 000 $"};
        return mapping[tick];
    };
""")
```

When I comment out this part, the plot suddenly appears. Any idea why this causes a problem?

For the record, I put this block there because I needed two ticks only on the x-axis, and I wanted them to display specific numbers that weren't linked to the data.

**EDIT**
I have found what causes this: syntax. It is linked to a [question I asked a few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453228/can-i-change-tickers-in-a-plot-to-custom-text-tickers/40469619#40469619). The code above was working for me because I was using Bokeh 0.12.2, but it was slightly different from the code given in the answer.

Here it is:

```
p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
    var mapping = {1.25: "20 000 $", 5.25: "50 000 $"};
    return mapping[tick];
""")
```

As explained in the comments of my past question, this code is right if Bokeh's version is 0.12.4+. And since I've been working on this project for a few months now, I guess Bokeh got updated in the meantime so I had to change the code in order to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. That tick formatter can come handy for me in the future. Just curious: You are still starting the server with "bokeh serve --show rrq_pour_server.py --host *:5006" ?

Comment: Well actually I found that the --show flag is for displaying in a web browser, so if the command is running on a server, it's not useful; it is if it's running on a desktop computer with a browser installed on. The rest is the same.

Comment: what about the --host *:5006  When I use that it doesn't work either. It says no matches found : *:5006. Only thing that works for me is what I show in my answer: `bokeh serve my_app.py --port XXXX --host NAMEOFSERVER:80 --prefix SOMEPREFIX`

Comment: But using the wildcard in the host flag isn't going to stay; it was only for testing purposes. Although I'm not familiar with this, my understanding is that it exposes the server to attacks. So for a secure deployment to the general Internet, I'll probably play around like you did and adopt a similar configuration with Apache.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your network configuration or firewall? Note that I'm not using Apache at all -- I'm just launching the Bokeh server from the server and tell it to listen to the port 5006 and accept everyone.

Comment: Yes, my server is behind a firewall. That's why I needed reverse-proxying.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using apache version 2.4.18 in a server running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS(xenial) and I am testing a simple bokeh server app with reverse-proxying. After some trial and error I found the following configuration working for me. I needed reverse-proxying for this to work. To start the server I use:

```
bokeh serve my_app.py --port XXXX --host NAMEOFSERVER:80 --prefix SOMEPREFIX
```

For this to work I created a `bokehserver.conf` file in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder with the following configuration:

```
<Location /SOMEPREFIX/my_app>
    ProxyPass         http://localhost:XXXX/SOMEPREFIX/my_app
    ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:XXXX/SOMEPREFIX/my_app
</Location>

<Location /SOMEPREFIX/my_app/ws>
    ProxyPass         ws://localhost:XXXX/SOMEPREFIX/my_app/ws
    ProxyPassReverse  ws://localhost:XXXX/SOMEPREFIX/my_app/ws
</Location>

Alias /SOMEPREFIX/static /some_place_in_server/bokeh/server/static
<Directory /some_place_in_server/bokeh/server/static>
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

then you have to reconfigure apache:

```
sudo a2ensite bokehserver.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

In my browser I use

```
http://NAMEOFSERVER/SOMEPREFIX/my_app
```

If I decide to use the `IP` instead of the domain name, then I have to run the bokeh server using that `IP`:

```
bokeh serve my_app.py --port XXXX --host IPnumber:80 --prefix SOMEPREFIX
```

And it will work for:

```
http://IPnumber/SOMEPREFIX/my_app
```

where SOMEPREFIX is of your choice, XXXX is the port you are using, my_app is the application you are testing. `some_place_in_server` is the place where your bokeh files are. I copy them in a different place place. The original place in my distribution is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/server/static` but is recommended to put is somewhere else. See [Running a Bokeh Server](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) specially the section Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

--host argument is deprecated now use something like
bokeh serve my_app.py --allow-websocket-origin=192.81.213.94 --port=5006