# Bokeh graph is not plotting

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, bokeh

This code does not plot anything for some reason. My initial guess is that there is some problem with p parameters, but I'm not pretty sure, so, please, help me out. In first part we download all the data and then we work with it and try to plot in the end, but it it only opens the new window without any kind of plot.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, save, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, BooleanFilter, \
    HoverTool, LinearAxis, NumeralTickFormatter, Range1d, RangeTool
stock_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTiM1scE44za7xyuheW_FrUkdSdOKipDgDOWa_03ixmJCWK_ReSqhjzax66nNHyDKARXWIXgFI_EW9X/pub?gid=1661368486&single=true&output=csv'
stock = pd.read_csv(stock_url)
metrics_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRDaf4y17OWjQqxODuxA4q4hsvXRkSqN0na1KtTIpvOZUdc7xHbrkhcygFfDIyVQWI2UbC3YcKUbser/pub?gid=981872466&single=true&output=csv'
metrics = pd.read_csv(metrics_url)
stock['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stock['Date'])
metrics['Quarter Ended'] = pd.to_datetime(metrics['Quarter Ended'])


def create_candlestick_chart(symbol='AAPL'):
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
        date=stock[stock['Symbol'] == symbol]['Date'],
        high=stock[stock['Symbol'] == symbol]['High'],
        low=stock[stock['Symbol'] == symbol]['Low'],
        open=stock[stock['Symbol'] == symbol]['Open'],
        close=stock[stock['Symbol'] == symbol]['Close'],
        volume=stock[stock['Symbol'] == symbol]['Volume'],
    ))
    p = figure(
        width=800,
        height=400,
        title=symbol,
        x_range=(min(stock[stock['Symbol'] == symbol]['Date']), max(stock[stock['Symbol'] == symbol]['Date'])),
        x_axis_type='datetime',
        x_axis_location='above',
        background_fill_color='#fbfbfb',
        tools='pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save',
        toolbar_location='right',
    )

    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = '#e5e5e5'
    p.ygrid.grid_line_alpha = 0.5
    p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '10px'
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Stock Price in USD'
    p.yaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='$0.00')

    p.y_range.start = min(stock[stock['Symbol'] == symbol]['Low']) * 0.9
    p.y_range.end = max(stock[stock['Symbol'] == symbol]['High']) * 1.1

    inc = source.data['close'] > source.data['open']
    dec = source.data['open'] > source.data['close']

    inc_view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[BooleanFilter(inc)])
    dec_view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[BooleanFilter(dec)])

    w = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000

    stock_segment = p.segment(
        x0='date', y0='high', x1='date', y1='low', color='black', source=source
    )

    stock_inc = p.vbar(
        x='date', top='close', bottom='open', width=w, fill_color='#D5E1DD', line_color='black', view=inc_view,
        source=source
    )

    stock_dec = p.vbar(
        x='date', top='open', bottom='close', width=w, fill_color='#F2583E', line_color='black', view=dec_view,
        source=source
    )

    y_volume = figure(
        y_range=p.y_range,
        width=80,
        height=p.height,
        tools='',
        toolbar_location=None,
        background_fill_color='#fbfbfb'
    )

    p.extra_y_ranges['volume'] = Range1d(
        start=0,
        end=max(source.data['volume']) * 2
    )

    y_volume.vbar(
        x='date',
        top='volume',
        source=source,
        width=0.5,
        alpha=0.5,
        color='navy',
        y_range_name='volume'
    )

    y_volume.axis.major_label_text_font_size = '10px'
    y_volume.axis.axis_label = 'Volume'
    y_volume.xaxis.visible = False
    y_volume.yaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='0.00a')

    y_volume_axis = LinearAxis(
        y_range_name='volume',
        axis_label='Volume',
        formatter=NumeralTickFormatter(format='0.00a')
    )

    p.add_layout(y_volume_axis, 'right')

    stock_volume = p.vbar(
        x='date',
        top='volume',
        source=source,
        width=0.5,
        alpha=0.5,
        color='navy',
        y_range_name='volume',
        view=inc_view,
        name='inc_volume'
    )

    stock_volume = p.vbar(
        x='date',
        top='volume',
        source=source,
        width=0.5,
        alpha=0.5,
        color='red',
        y_range_name='volume',
        view=dec_view,
        name='dec_volume'
    )

    hover_stock = HoverTool()
    hover_stock.tooltips = [
        ('Date', '@date{%F}'),
        ('Open', '@open{$0.00}'),
        ('Close', '@close{$0.00}'),
        ('High', '@high{$0.00}'),
        ('Low', '@low{$0.00}'),
        ('Volume', '@volume{0,0}'),
    ]

    hover_stock.formatters = {
        '@date': 'datetime',
    }

    hover_stock.renderers = [
        stock_inc,
        stock_dec,
    ]
    p.add_tools(hover_stock)

    p.output_backend = 'svg'

    return p
p = create_candlestick_chart()
show(p)
```

Comment: It seems to run correctly and I am able to see the graph on my machine (using jupyter notebook). So, suspect it might have to do something with libraries. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856999/bokeh-plots-just-bring-up-a-blank-window) to check if you have everything set up correctly

Comment: Sorry, could you maybe share the picture via imgur or something? Cuz my previous work with bokeh plotted everything perfectly and I asked my friend to run this code and he also got an empty html page.

Comment: Added the output below. Cant add it comments as far as I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code ran fine and here is the output pic. Note that the output is .SVG, but I cant post it here, so sending screen shot. See if this helps...

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much, it plots exactly as it should be, I just cannot understand why cant I plot it...

Comment: I am almost certain it has to do with the required import(s). Check the link and see if you are missing some libraries. Good luck !